# Can tests be written for selenium rc with VB.Net?

Tags: selenium

Can test scripts be written in VB.Net for Selenium? Or is it only c# (Apart from java, perl, php etc).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, BUT the Selenium tools won't export to VB explicitly, you'll need to manually convert it (or use an automated tool) from C#.

[This](http://jorno.org/20100304/selenium-for-vb-net/) article shows how the code looks in VB, and gives a link for a Conversion Tool  which I've linked [here](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/) also